# How to model tags in the database?

Tags: database, tags, normalization, tag-cloud

I have an existing webapp and want to add a tag feature so that users can tag existing objects. The question is should I add a tag column to each object? or should I normalize it and use a tag table where each object will have a collection of tags? I am leaning towards the latter because it feels cleaner, easier to report on and easier to create a tag cloud. But since I know this has been solved 1000 times I wanted to ask and see if I am missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do you foresee users needing to associate more than one tag with an object?

If **not**, add the TAG_ID fk to the OBJECT table.  Otherwise, you'd need three tables in total to correctly model a many-to-many relationship:

OBJECT

- OBJECT_ID (pk)

OBJECT_TAG_XREF

- OBJECT_ID (pk, fk to OBJECT)
- TAG_ID (pk, fk to TAG)

TAG

- TAG_ID (pk)

Comment: How would this change to tie tags to users? Would OBJECT_ID become USER_ID?

Comment: @JuniperAsh: You'd have to add a `user_id` column to `OBJECT_TAG_XREF` - same as the other two columns, primary key and foreign key to the users table.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you should normalize it.  The 'tag column' is either going to support only one tag per record, or is going to have hideous search performance.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely normalize. A table for tags, a table for your existing objects, and a table of links between them.