# Best model for a system of tags

Tags: mysql, database, tags, data-modeling

what is the best model for a system of tags? for example, a topic can have `N` tags, tags and `N` may be related to `N` **threads**, if I create a table, tags and posts a table and this table tags, I had the `ID of the posts`, and the tag, would be duplicating many records as another topic to add this tag, which is the best way to avoid this?

[image]

---

@Quentin, the problem continues, it will repeat the records in the table post_tags

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `posts` (
  `pid` bigint(22) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `author` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `content` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=2 ;

INSERT INTO `posts` (`pid`, `author`, `content`) VALUES
(1, 'Andrey Knupp Vital', 'Hello World !');

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tagged` (
  `pid` bigint(22) NOT NULL,
  `tid` bigint(22) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pid`,`tid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `tagged` (`pid`, `tid`) VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tags` (
  `tid` bigint(22) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tag` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

INSERT INTO `tags` (`tid`, `tag`) VALUES
(1, 'main'),
(2, 'hello');
```

Comment: There are multiple *existing* tag systems -- I forget the names (nor do I use PHP) -- and *at least three* different ways of approaching this problem, depending upon requirements. Some are "less pure" from a design standpoint than others.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20856/how-do-you-recommend-implementing-tags-or-tagging , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329887/how-to-model-tags-in-the-database , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3539744/best-way-to-store-tags-in-a-database

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)

It will have at least two columns. "Posts" and "Tags" with the primary key being defined across the pair of them (if the database allows it, otherwise a third column for the primary key).

[image]